# does lucene update stop working in hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

During the startup of the server the indexing works fine(the indexes are created and search works fine). But when we try to update some indexes we got the lock exception and indexes not work and search don't give correct result.

Below if the error log. The same is happening in the linux server.

```
2023-09-07T11:39:50,437 [ERROR] [Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index com.demoBO] [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler] - HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this virtual machine: D:\test\com.demoBO\write.lock
Primary Failure:
    Entity com.demoBO  Id 532  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.UpdateLuceneWork

org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this virtual machine: D:\test\com.demoBO\write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:127) ~[lucene-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5 b3441673c21c83762035dc21d3827ad16aa17b68 - sarowe - 2017-10-20 08:57:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41) ~[lucene-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5 b3441673c21c83762035dc21d3827ad16aa17b68 - sarowe - 2017-10-20 08:57:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45) ~[lucene-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5 b3441673c21c83762035dc21d3827ad16aa17b68 - sarowe - 2017-10-20 08:57:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:776) ~[lucene-core-5.5.5.jar:5.5.5 b3441673c21c83762035dc21d3827ad16aa17b68 - sarowe - 2017-10-20 08:57:09]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:127) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:93) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:118) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:204) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:82) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:47) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:167) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:153) [hibernate-search-engine-5.11.6.Final.jar:5.11.6.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_302]
2023-09-07T11:39:50,453 [ERROR] [Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index com.demoBO] [org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask] - HSEARCH000072: Couldn't open the IndexWriter because of previous error: operation skipped, index ouf of sync!
```

My demoBO looks like:-

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "DEMO_TB")
public class demoBO extends AbstractBO implements Serializable,
        Comparable<demoBO> {

    @Column(name = "active")
    @Field(analyze=Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private Boolean status;
    
    @Column(name = "deletion")
    @Field(analyze=Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private Boolean deletion;

    @Column(name = "keyValue", length = 256)
    @Field(analyze=Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String keyValue;


    @Transient
    private int status = 0;
```

During the startup of server the code use to create indexes(after this a write.lock file is generated): -

```
entityManager = (EntityManager) applicationContext.getBean(entityManager);
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(DemoBO.class).startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means two separate instances of Lucene / Hibernate Search are trying to open the same index simultaneously, which is not possible.

Most likely you're starting multiple EntityManagerFactory at the same time for the same model. You should not.

Comment: is there a way that i can check if I'm starting multiple EntityManagerFactory at the same time for the same model? Also, i belive this is not happening during the startup of server?

Comment: Well logs would be the easiest way I guess. Look for duplicates, especially when setting the log level of category "org.hibernate" to DEBUG or TRACE. Beyond that, without knowing your code I can't really help. And yes this happens after startup, but when lazily initializing the index writer which is a singleton. Unless somehow you gave the same name to two indexes, but I believe there are protections against that in Hibernate Search.

Comment: @yrosiere, thankyou for the help, but i just added the hibernate property which doesn't create any lock as only one user can update the indexes. "hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy" value="none"